# How to reference a module in its own folders?

Tags: python, python-import, relative-path

I have python module, that i added to some other source root folder like this

```
MyProject/my_new_file.py
MyProject/MyModule/__init__.py
MyProject/MyModule/script1.py
MyProject/MyModule/script2.py
```

And because root source is folder "MyProject", script1.py cannot include script2.py file like this:

```
from script2 import my_awesome_function
```

Does someone know a way that my modules imports are isolated within their own folder, so i dont have to reference import path from source root

Comment: See [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [relative imports](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references):

```
from .script2 import my_awesome_function
```

Comment: Yes, but is there any way that i could set sys.path() in __init__.py so i wouldnt have to set these relative imports everywhere

Comment: @JernejHabjan: `sys.path` is a modifiable list, so you can add, change, and delete items from/in it if you wish.